# Modifying scroll behavior in BottomSheet in Jetpack Compose

Tags: scroll, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

By default, in the ModalBottomSheetLayout in Jetpack Compose, when you try to scroll its content, instead of scrolling, the bottom sheet expands itself. Is there any way I can change this behavior and limit the max height of the bottom sheet? I want to be able to scroll the content and not expand the sheet.

I tried looking into the source code of ModalBottomSheet and it looks like it always gets the touch events first and only passes it down to the content when it has fully utilised them. I am not sure how to reverse this behavior, so, the content should always get the scroll events and only if it cannot consume it, it should go to the bottom sheet.